# too many values to unpack in apply function (python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, valueerror

i wrote a simple function to split a string.

```
def split2(target):
   (key, host) = target.split('_')
   return (key, host)

(combined['host'], combined['timestamp']) = combined['key'].apply(split2)
```

`combined['key']` is a pandas series that make of string like `'ibmserver_4/12/2007'`

after trying multiple times, i still have the ValueError: too many values to unpack. if i reduce the return parameter in the split2 function to one, that works fine.

Can someone advise what's wrong with the code above and how should I rectify? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be to split the `str` directly with pandas, using `expand=True` creates separate columns, e.g.:

```
>>> combined['key'].str.split('_', expand=True)
           0          1
0  ibmserver  4/12/2007
```

The correct way to assign that to multiple columns is:

```
>>> combined[['host', 'timestamp']] = combined['key'].str.split('_', expand=True)
>>> combined
                   key       host  timestamp
0  ibmserver_4/12/2007  ibmserver  4/12/2007
```

To make your function work you would need to convert the returned tuple into a series, e.g.:

```
>>> combined[['host', 'timestamp']] = combined['key'].apply(split2).apply(pd.Series)
```